# I'm trying to UV Unwrap my character body, but I have these long stick-like sections and don't know how to go about fixing it

Tags: uv, topology

I'm a total beginner, trying to make my first ever character to hopefully eventually use in Unity. I'm trying to UV Unwrap my character's body in preparation for texturing, but there's these strange long sections of mesh that I don't have the slightest idea to go about resolving.

When I highlight the body object, and select UV Sync, which I think reveals the inital unwrap, to the right, there's this long mesh section:

[image]

When I begin to go around the body and Live Unwrap parts of it, such as marking a seam around the wrist, I can see that somehow these long sections are attached throughout the whole arm and lead through the body, possibly originating from the head, but when I go into Xray mode, I don't see any accidentally placed faces or anything like that. The inside of the body seems hollow as it should be, so I have no idea where these are coming from.

Example of when I mark a seam around the wrist and select the stick-like objects, then L to isolate the areas of the mesh:

[image]

[image]

Originally, I made the body and sculped the head separately, so recently, I did have to add a bunch of edge loops in the neck (which lead down the arm, shoulder, and into the hand) in order to be able to have the same number of vertices on the neck and head so that I could attach the head. I'm guessing it's caused from that but it's just a guess?

Could any help me out here and help me figure this out. I'm so new to all this I don't really know what to do to fix this issue so I can finish the unwrap and prepare for texturing.

The blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xrg8hpo06onqq505weyoe/Finishing-Details.blend?rlkey=493xvo2kh6run16ptilpcpbqj&dl=0

Edit: Ok, so, going around and selecting individual faces, it seems these long weird sections are primarily coming from the lips and the nostrils. At least so far, it's hard to find all the areas causing this. It's just, I don't understand why, or if I should fix it or how.

[image]